# How to get count of id's with missing values that are present in observations without missing values using SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table as shown below. The table has `id` observations with missing values and others with actual values. What I want to get is a count of `id`'s only where `value` is missing. In this case it would be only `id` 4, so the count would be 1. How can I do this using SQL?

```
id | value
---+-------
1  | home
2  | out
3  | home
1  | 
2  |
4  |
```

Comment: tag appropriate database name.

Comment: Define *"missing value"* is it `NULL` or `''` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the count, you can do:

```
select count(distinct id)
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.value is not null);
```

Alternatively, you could use two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select id
      from t
      group by id
      having count(value) = 0
     ) x;
```

Or, if your database supports it, `except`:

```
select count(*)
from (select id from t where value is null
      except
      select id from t where value is not null
     ) x;
```

`except` removes duplicates, so `distinct` is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can do aggregation :

```
select id
from table t
group by id
having count(value) = 0;
```

Comment: This will work only with `NULL` values, let's hope this is the case

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
SELECT id 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN value IS NULL OR value = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(ID)
```